# Unable to bypass system checks to allow upgrade to Windows 11

Tags: windows-update, windows-11-upgrade

Is there a way (that actually works) to bypass these checks in order to upgrade to Windows 11? Also, hoping to do this with Windows Update as opposed to downloading an ISO and going that route. In additon, my computer does have TPM and SecureBoot enabled.

[image: PC Health Check Error]

Comment: You can dismiss the warning so it just appears at the bottom of Update as just one line;  But otherwise you cannot bypass it to upgrade.  If your machine is not compliant, you cannot just upgrade. You have to see the registry flag to permit installation or join the Windows Insider program.

Comment: Regarding the TPM, it sees it, but it's TPM 1.2 and the requirement is TPM 2.0.

Comment: In order to install Windows 11 you will have to enable both the bypass key for TPM and CPU.  How you do that has been answered in a previous question.  I am on my way out to a function so I can't find the duplicate myself.  Rufus can generate a bootable media flash storage device that can do it for you if you don't know how.

Comment: Yes, already have the following registry entries:

"HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /V "BypassSecureBootCheck" /T REG_DWORD /D "1"
"HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\LabConfig" /V "BypassTPMCheck" /T REG_DWORD /D "1"
"HKLM\SYSTEM\MoSetup" /V "AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU" /T REG_DWORD /D "1"

Thanx again.

Comment: Why do you want to install a Windows version that will work badly or not at all on your computer, when you already have one that works perfectly well?

Comment: You have to download a Windows 11 ISO, mount it, and run setup.exe.  You will be unable to bypass the requirement checks by using Windows Update.  “An image install of Windows 11 will not check for the following requirements: TPM 2.0 (at least TPM 1.2 is required) and CPU family and model.” **It’s impossible to bypass the requirements check and upgrade to Windows 11 through Windows Update.** I will update one of my existing answers and flag this question as a duplicate sometime in the future

Comment: I have a machine - TPM1.2, UEFI, Secure Boot.  It ran Windows 11 until about 2 months ago when Control Pane and its functions would not work. Even a fresh install did not fix it . New battery and back to Windows 10 Pro and it is working fine that way. Think twice before forcing Windows 11 onto it as the current version of Windows 11 may not even run on it.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way (that works) to bypass these checks to upgrade to Windows 11?

You must use BypassSecureBootCheck and [AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ways-to-install-windows-11-e0edbbfb-cfc5-4011-868b-2ce77ac7c70e) to install Windows 11.  However, you cannot install Windows 11 using Windows Update since your system is incompatible with Windows 11.

You must download a Windows 11 ISO and mount the ISO while within Windows to bypass the compatibility checks.  You must still use the BypassSecureBootCheck and AllowUpgradesWithUnsupportedTPMOrCPU to upgrade to Windows 11. You can accomplish that using [this](https://github.com/AveYo/MediaCreationTool.bat) script, Rufus, or [UUPDUMP](https://uupdump.net/)

> Also, hoping to do this with Windows Update as opposed to downloading an ISO and going that route.

This won't be possible.